# Conversion of seconds to duration working on one server, but not another

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to convert a number of seconds into days, hours and minutes. The code is below:

```
    $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
    $dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes');
```

On my deployment server it works fine:
1 days, 4 hours, 27 minutes

On my development server (XAMPP), I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character in D:\220909_XAMPP\htdocs\PC\PupController\worker.php:261 Stack trace: #0 D:\220909_XAMPP\htdocs\PC\PupController\worker.php(261): DateTime->__construct('@') #1 D:\220909_XAMPP\htdocs\PC\PupController\index.php(92): Pup->lastMonth() #2 {main} thrown in D:\220909_XAMPP\htdocs\PC\PupController\worker.php on line 261

Can someone help?

Comment: Make sure that $seconds value is numerical and not containing any characters in beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had forgotten to change a setting on one copy!